# Java class, Arraylist with multiple types

Tags: java, android, arraylist, server-communication

i'm new to Android & Java and have a question regarding my server-app-communication. My server always returns a JSON output with "Code", "Message" and "Data". Like this:

```
e.g: {"code":200,"msg":"success","data":[{"track_id":123},{"track_id":124},{"track_id":125}]}
e.g: {"code":200,"msg":"success","data":[{"type":"car","length":100},{"type":"train","length":500},{"type":"foot","length":3}]}
```

I want to use a class like this to work with the data:

```
public class ServerResponse {
    private int code;
    private String msg;
    private List<> data;
}
```

But here is my problem. I don't want to give a specific type like "car", "login" etc. to the List. Depending on my request I want to create the ServerResponse-class with a List-Type "car", another with List-Type "Locations" etc.

Is there a way to use the class ServerResponse with multiple type of ArrayLists or do I have to copy this class several times for every list-type I'd like to use?

I'm sorry if there's already a solution somewhere here, but I do not know what I have to search for. And for what I searched, I couldn't find a propper solution.

Best regards
Michael

Comment: You could create a super-type for 'car', 'login', 'location' and so on. Then instantiate the list inside ServerResponse as List<SuperType> and put there Car, Login or Location objects in there

Comment: I don't think Car and Login should have the same parent

Comment: I answered already, but now i started to struggle with your text, do you want multiple `ServerResponse` with an `ArrayList` of one Type or one `ServerResponse` with multiple different Classes in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @CarlosRodriguez I believe they can. Something like `ResponseItem` may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into Java [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

```
public class ServerResponse<T> { 
    private int code;
    private String msg;
    private List<T> data;
}
```

T can be whatever type you want it to be, so your list will then be of that type. Then your getter/setter methods can return or accept type T.

Now let us assume your response was for a Car object. You would do this

```
private ServerResponse<Car> mCarResponse = new ServerResponse<>();
```

Now you can put a method inside your ServerResponse class like this.

```
public class ServerResponse<T> { 
    private int code;
    private String msg;
    private List<T> data;

    public List<T> getResponseObjectList(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

You will now get a `List<Car>` object.

Comment: thank you very much.
Helped me a lot to get a better code quality.
That was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Michael, That's great! Generics completely transformed the way I coded when I first learned about them. It is a wonderful feature to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the Serverrespone generic aswell.

```
public class GenericResponse <T>{
   private int code;
   private String msg;
   private List<T> data;
}
```